# Assigning type to a React SFC function declaration in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, you can assign a type of `React.FC<PropsType>` to a variable so that it is understood as a React Stateless Functional Component like so:

```
//Interface declaration
interface ButtonProps {
  color: string,
  text: string,
  disabled?: boolean
}

// Function Component
let Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = function(props){
  return <div> ... </div> ;
}
```

However, I am having trouble understanding how to assign the same type to a FC built as a function declaration:

```
//Props interface already declared
function Button(props){
  render <div> ... </div>;
}
```

I could assign the type to the `props` argument, and it would partly help since it would show what I expect to get from the caller (minus the `children` prop) but I don't think that would help with any intellisense from the calling context. I also have no idea what to set as the return type of the second example.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `function Button(props: ButtonProps){return <div> ... </div>;}` I get full intelisense on the properties at call site, not sure what more you could want :)

Comment: Huh, you do. I must have not been very observant. Still, for curiosity or code styling purposes, is there a way to assign the type to the function declaration?

Comment: You could attempt to write `const Button: ComponentType<ButtonProps> = (props) => <div>...</div>;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you've found the answer by now, but adding a static type to a *named function* is nearly identical to how you did it in your initial example

Based on your example:

```js
//Props interface already declared
function Button(props): React.ReactElement<Props> {
  render <div> ... </div>;
}

// Or you could store the function in a named variable
const ButtonComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = function Button(props): React.ReactElement<Props> {
  render <div> ... </div>;
}

// Using shorthand type
const ButtonComponent: React.FC<Props> = function Button(props) {
  render <div> ... </div>;
}
```

You can read up more on adding types to react components in this [article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-statically-type-react-components-with-typescript)

> **Note:** Best practice is to use `React.FC` instead of `React.SFC` since it's now deprecated in recent versions of React

Comment: Thanks for the correction about `React.FC`, I have corrected that on the sample!

Comment: About your answer, I tried it on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-noether-kwgre?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FProductDisplay.tsx) to make sure, but the example you're giving me is not typing the Button component as a React element, it is typing the return object of Button as a React element. Note in the sample the editor marks the return statement of the function a an error.

Comment: You're right, sorry about the misleading type, I've updated my answer with the correct return type of the named function. In terms of your original question about applying the `React.FC` type to ***named functions***, I think it's unnecessary in this context because you've explicitly stated it's type via the use of the ***function*** keyword